# How to run a code after 10 seconds for a single time in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, oop, time

I've seen a few multithreading posts regarding running a code every 10 seconds, but how do you run a code only once after x seconds?

Specifically, I am trying to create a class method that executes some code and calls another method after 10 seconds once but still allows other methods to be called in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer)

E.g.:

```
from threading import Timer

class Test:
    def start(self):
            Timer(10, self.some_method, ()).start()

    def some_method(self):
            print "called some_method after 10 seconds"


t = Test()
t.start()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How exactly does the program stop?

Comment: @PBuddy: You can use [`Timer.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ I use Boost to do similar tasks. Look at deadline_timer http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html for example. The page has some examples as well to get you started. Unfortunately you need to use io_service to make use of deadline_timer.

Python has twisted framework to do the same http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorTime.html#callLater

In sytem programming world you could use timer_create http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html for example (depending on the OS you are using) and I would not go that route unless you have a good reason todo so.

Answer (score 0):

Implement @timeout decorator and put before the function you want to setup.

Use **signal** on Unix like OS, refer to [timeout_decorator](https://github.com/pnpnpn/timeout-decorator/blob/master/timeout_decorator/timeout_decorator.py). Since Windows doesn't implement signals at the system level, you have to use [InterruptableThread](https://gist.github.com/vadimg/2902788).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What exactly is a signal?

Comment: @PBuddy "A signal is an asynchronous notification sent to a process or to a specific thread within the same process in order to notify it of an event that occurred. " - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)